# How can I assign a value in my text file to another value?

Tags: c#, console-application

I currently have very basic code that allows me to write whatever I want into a text file, which then saves once I exit the application. I can add extra lines to this file by simply running the program again and adding more lines via ReadLine() before repeating the process.

But I do not believe that with this code, the program recognizes the different "items" in my text file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (File.Exists("test.txt"))
            {
                string items = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
                Console.WriteLine("Current inventory stock:");
                Console.WriteLine(content);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a new tool into the inventory: ");
            string newItems = Console.ReadLine();
            while (newItems != "exit")
            {
                File.AppendAllText("test.txt", newItems + Environment.NewLine);
                newItems = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

My text file looks like this (all placeholder names):

```
ItemOne, ItemInfo, 2
ItemTwo, ItemInfo, 6
ItemThree, ItemInfo, 4
ItemFour, ItemInfo, 1
ItemFive, ItemInfo, 7
```

I am trying to get the int value to match their corresponding item. So "2" should be apart of "ItemOne" and none of the others. Are there any tutorials or resources/info for this?

I had a similar program that I created but that was so much easier because the textfile was read only so I didn't have to deal with this.

Comment: Why does a program that simply appends lines to a file need to "recognizes the different 'items'" in the first place? Why is that useful?

Comment: You are writing a piece of text (like: "ItemOne, ItemInfo, 2"). Your computer does not know more than that this is a piece of text. It cannot recognize thing like numbers and, when you split the text on ',', that you have 3 parts.  That's where programming start.  Any resources/info on this would mean a basic course in programming.

Comment: So I'm actually creating an inventory system so basically I have items that are "stock". I can add new stock by creating new lines (with the code I have) but I am trying to also just like a regular shop, be able to increase the stock, which is the int value at the end

Comment: So you're basically producing csv content. Have a look at https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Class to hold your inventory items.

After the input you can do:

```
Inventory inv = new Inventory(newItems);
```

After this `inv.AmountInStock` should give the value of the third item (when splitting on ',') so the value you have entered to be on stock.

(But I am not sure about the meaning of your input, I guessed the meaning of the different values you provide )

```cs
public class Inventory {
    public string ItemName {get; set;}
    public string ItemInfo { get;set;}
    public int AmountInStock {get; set;}

    public Inventory(string s) {
          string[] x = s.Split(',');
          this.ItemName = x[0].Trim();
          this.ItemInfo = x[1].Trim();
          this.AmountInStock = Convert.ToInt32(x[2]);
    }
}
```